# i3 for dual-monitor on laptop

Tags: display, hdmi, i3-wm, multiple-monitors

I am using i3 as the window manager on my laptop. Now I want it to work with my HDMI monitor. So far I have this is my `.3/config`:

```
exec xrandr --output eDP1 --auto --output HDMI1 --auto --left-of eDP1
```

This works quite well but only as long as my HDMI monitor is plugged in. When it is not I have half of my workspaces not visible since they are not displayed on my laptops monitor.

How can I make it detect whether or not the other monitor is plugged in and have a configuration for both cases? 
Also can it automatically detect when the HDMI is (un)plugged and change the configursation accordingly? Or do I have to bind it to a key to check for monitors?

Answer (score 11):

Try this instead:

```
xrandr | grep 'HDMI1 connected' &&
    xrandr --output eDP1 --auto --output HDMI1 --auto --left-of eDP1
```

That will run the `xrandr` command only if the `HMDI1` screen is connected. I don't know the details of the format of `.3/config` (although I do know it will ignore anything after the `exec` line, are you sure you want this with `exec`?), so if that doesn't work just put it in a script and call the script from `config`.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick for me: `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto --left-of LVDS-1`